# CSS3 animation not working with jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, css-animations

I'm using [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) to format a table. I have a CSS3 animation set up to add a highlight to a row in the table after a delay but it doesn't work.

If I disable Datatables, the animation works fine. Even stranger, if I change the background animation into a color animation, it also works.

Watching from Chrome's inspector, I can see that the class is being added but it just doesn't appear to be doing anything...

What am I missing?

JS

```
$('#<%=gvMyGrid.ClientID%>').dataTable({
    "order": [[1, 'desc']],
    "columnDefs": [
        { "orderable": false, "targets": oIndex }, //disable sorting on the "edit" column
        { "type": "date", "targets": parseInt($('#<%=hfDateColumnNum.ClientID%>').val()) },
        { "visible": false, "targets": 4 }
    ]
});

setTimeout(function () {
    var alertRow = document.getElementsByClassName('alert-target')[0];

    alertRow.scrollIntoView();
    alertRow.classList.add('alert-highlight');
}, 3000);
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes yellow-fade {
    0% {
        background: yellow;
    }

    100% {
        background: none;
    }
}

@keyframes yellow-fade {
    0% {
        background: yellow;
    }

    100% {
        background: none;
    }
}

.alert-highlight {
    -webkit-animation: yellow-fade 2s ease-in 1;
    animation: yellow-fade 2s ease-in 1;
}
```

Comment: Check the element in the DOM inspector. It's possible your `.alert-highlight` isn't of a high enough precedence to override the existing Datatables styling

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - How would I get around that? I tried adding `!important` to the styles but it didn't work.

Comment: If that's happening you need to make the selector more specific than those added by DataTables. This is assuming that this is the problem, which you'd need to confirm.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Hmm... you may be right about the specificity. I ruled out that possibility because `!important` didn't work but if I set the delay long enough out to uncheck some of the background styles coming from Bootstrap, it looks like it works. Doing some more testing...

Comment: People put a lot more faith in `!important` than it deserves. It's a last-resort tactic that you shouldn't ever really use. If you could add a working example of the issue to the question I'll gladly help you diagnose it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I only use it for quick testing to confirm I have a specificity issue. Not sure why `!important` didn't work in this instance but you were right. Fixing the selector to be more specific than the bootstrap styles worked like a charm. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added the answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Watching from Chrome's inspector, I can see that the class is being added but it just doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Given this behaviour it sounds likely that your `.alert-highlight` class is not specific enough to override the default styling of the Datatable.

To fix this you need to make the rule more specific. Something like this, for example:

```css
#container table#foo .data td.alert-highlight {
  -webkit-animation: yellow-fade 2s ease-in 1;
  animation: yellow-fade 2s ease-in 1;
}
```